# datamodel connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamodel

I'm struggling with a new application where I have a User model wich has several associations with itself.

For example a user can have students / parents / administrators, but all of those associations are users as well.

My idea was to create a connection model where I specify the associations id's and the association type. Unfortunately I dont know how to implement this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When a model references itself, it is a self-join. See [here.](http://www.sqltutorial.org/sqlselfjoin.aspx) and also google for "self join".

**Re: "connection model" needed?**

Answer: Rather than "connection model," better terms are "many to many table" or "[junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)"

A many to many table is only needed if your data has a many to many relationship. Otherwise, you just need a one to one or many to one relationship.

**"A user can have students"** The key question is, can one student also have many "users"? If so, then you need a many to many table, otherwise not.

For parents, you could say that a user has exactly zero or one father. If so then a many to many table is not needed.

**Edited:** Oops, I realize that I no longer know this "cold". I'd have to experiment with sample code to get it right. And unfortunately I don't have the time right now. My apologies.

See [Self-Joins doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)